# Fixed tenure fund versus fixed maturity plan

Tags: mutual-funds, india

Is there a difference between a fixed tenure fund and a fixed maturity plan? For instance this page on valueresearch lists both under the title FMP.
http://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/fmpnfo.asp

These products used to mention an indicative yield in the prospectus. They don't seem to anymore. Don't they need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mean the same.

SEBI guideline discourages to indicate an Yield when its not gaurenteed. This was to help investors not to get this schemes confused with Bonds/or other Fixed Interest instruments.

Answer (score 1):

FTFs are just another name for an FMP, the idea being they are closed ended funds and you can't get in after the Initial New Fund Offer (NFO). You may not be able to exit prematurely but certain funds let you out with a penalty.

Indicative yields were banned by SEBI after they figured it was being used as a quasi guarantee. The problem is in the mechanics. The fund migh say 10-11%, but by the time they collect the money the yields in the market could have slipped to 9.5%. Then people will complain and SEBI, instead of saying buyer beware, said that if there's no guarantee there's no reason to do the indicative peg either.